# Usar el modulo Pyautogui python

Tags: python

Necesito usar el modulo "Pyautogui" en Python, pero siempre me da error, llevo 3 dias probando de todo por favor ayudenmen...

Necesito que posicione el muse y de click sobre la imagen que coincida, es el recorte de el logo de el boton de windows, ya probe con confidence y otras cosas creo que ahi se aprecia el error igual estare al pendiente de ayuda

+573246299408 Escribanme si pueden enserio quiero ayuda, ya no sé que hacer...

Pero me da error por no reconocer la imagen o algo asi, ya probe con distintas imagenes, no es el problema quiza no estoy ponoiendo algo bien en fin por favor ayudenmen, puedo compartir mi pantalla[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

SOLO QUE FUNCIONE ESTO ES TODO YA PODRIA CON EL RESTO:

import pyautogui
cords = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('win_2.png')
pyautogui.click(cords)
print(cords)

ESTE ES EL ERROR QUE DA:

PS C:\Users\Maicoll\Desktop\NameBOT> & C:/Users/Maicoll/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/python.exe c:/Users/Maicoll/Desktop/NameBOT/VisorWInterprete/test2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\Maicoll\Desktop\NameBOT\VisorWInterprete\test2.py", line 3, in 
cords = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('win_2.png', confidence=0.9)
File "C:\Users\Maicoll\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyautogui_*init*_.py", line 175, in wrapper
return wrappedFunction(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Maicoll\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyautogui_*init*_.py", line 213, in locateOnScreen
return pyscreeze.locateOnScreen(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Maicoll\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyscreeze_*init*_.py", line 372, in locateOnScreen
screenshotIm = screenshot(region=None) # the locateAll() function must handle cropping to return accurate coordinates, so don't pass a region here.
File "C:\Users\Maicoll\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyscreeze_*init*_.py", line 144, in wrapper
raise PyScreezeException('The Pillow package is required to use this function.')
pyscreeze.PyScreezeException: The Pillow package is required to use this function.
PS C:\Users\Maicoll\Desktop\NameBOT>

Comment: Primero que nada, el código va como texto, cosa que sea llegar y copiar. En formato imagen no sirve de mucho.

Comment: El error es claro: *The Pillow package is required...*. Instálalo: `pip install --upgrade Pillow`

Comment: Edite la pregunta, con un codigo pequeño y el error, solo necesito que funcione y es todo ya puedo continuar pero no me da coordenadas ni posiciona el mouse ni nada, si solo muevo el mouse a una coordenada si lo hace pero si busco la coordenada con respecto a una imagen no hace nada.

Comment: y a lo de... pip install --upgrade Pillow ya lo he hecho varias veces pero no funciona en nada, sigue el mismo error

Comment: por favor quien pueda ayudarme le puedo compartir pantalla, este es mi whatasapp +573167932432

Comment: Es en inglés, pero ¿te funciona esto? https://stackoverflow.com/a/65361299/1545868

Comment: ya lo veo gracias de antemano